# VueJs - Nesting custom components

Tags: nested, components, vue.js

I have some proble. I'm going to create few components, and I try to nest them. So I have an example

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <image-slider>
            <slide image="image01.jpg"></slide-image>
            <slide image="image02.jpg"></slide-image>
            <slide image="image03.jpg"></slide-image>
        </image-slider>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is static HTML, this content is not adding with VueJS.
I tried to create them, but I can't.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your javascript code?

Comment: I don't have JS code, because  I can't do this

Answer (score 0):

if image-slider and slide are all custom components, then you can create slide component first, create image-slider later, and refer to slide from image-slider, here is a jsFiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/006cce2d/)

```
 <image-slider :images="['http://placehold.it/350x150','http://placehold.it/200x100']">
</image-slider>

 // use slide only

 <slide image="http://placehold.it/200x100"></slide>
```

Comment: So it's not possible to create custom componets?

Comment: why not? the example has two custom components namely: slide and image-slider

Comment: but I want to create, that will be look like my example.